# Difference between using a "result variable" vs raw variable return in a function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So I'm messing around using variables for a menu / calculator program that I was told to alter in one of my "Practice Problems" as shown here:

> 2. Make your calculator program perform computations in a separate function for each type of computation.

My question is when making these 4 functions to handle each of the four simple arithmetic operations, I wasn't sure what the difference was between using the following syntax here:

```
double addition(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

As apposed to using a local scoped "result" variable to return the value?

```
double addition(double x, double y)
{
    double result;
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}
```

The only conclusion I could come up with is that there might be more manipulation of the input x and y values in a more advanced arithmetic operation such as area of a circle etc so more variables would be needed to carry out that computation.

Lastly, which of the two is a better practice to use? I know this is a secondary question but I just want to learn the correct methodology as to not learn bad programming habits.

Comment: In the second case, generally you want to say `double result = x + y;` Always initialise variables wherever possible.

Comment: I doubt a reasonable modern compiler would produce different assembly between those two, though technically the second is creating a `double` and then initalising a `double` after, so with a crappy old compiler and no optimisations, you might see a slight performance benefit to the first due to the extra work, and if declared as `inline`, the higher probability that the first would actually be `inline`d. I do also prefer the first in general as it's more expressive and concise. If either of those were to be declared as member functions, they could be declared `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is compiled with optimizing compilers. This means that you can write the same code in different ways and get the same assembly output.

Adding an extra variable, usually gets optimized away when this doesn't change the lifetime of variables. (or at least the noticeable side effects)

Adding an extra variable has some advantages:

- It has a name, which might make it more readable
- For debug builds, it is easier to see the value and add breakpoints on the variable

For the example you've shown, I expect all modern compilers to generate the same code.

Side note: It's better not to have uninitialized memory, you can declare your variable while assigning. (`double result = x + y`), tnx Neil Butterworth for suggesting this in comments.

Answer (score -1):

> Lastly, which of the two is a better practice to use?

The first is better.

The second needlessly introduces an extra variable into the scope of the function, which makes the code just a little bit harder to read and understand. Extra variables may increase readability, but not in such a tiny function.

What's worse is that you also do not initialise the object but allow it to live for some time without a defined value, thus requiring an assignment later on. This not only adds *another* layer of complication but also makes the code more dangerous, because you'd trigger undefined behaviour if you accidentally tried to read the value before the assignment:

```
double addition(double x, double y)
{
    double result;
    std::cout << result; // may crash, randomly alter the function result, do other bad things
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}
```

Another consequence is that you cannot use `auto` or `const` (or `auto const`):

```
double addition(double x, double y)
{
    auto result; // does not compile
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}

double addition(double x, double y)
{
    double const result; // does not compile
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}
```

By the way, I don't buy the debugger arguments in favour of the second practice. A decent debugger is very well capable of showing you the values of unnamed objects. Here is an example from Visual Studio 2017:

[image: Visual Studio 2017 debugger screenshot]